# Remove class by href

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple script to block users in certain forum. It's my first attempt with Javascript. From quick look I noticed the forum not using ids for users but rather ids for posts which created me a problem to find a certain user and remove him.

That being said I did find out that in a class named "username online popupctrl" there is an href with link to the user profile as can be seen here:

[image]

but the problem is that removing only that class will not remove his post, in order to remove the post I need to remove the post class that is the parent of parent of parent... of the class. As can be seen here:

[image]

I did manage to find all the posts with this script:

```
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for (var i = divs.length; i;) {
    var div = divs[--i];
    if (div.id.indexOf("post") > -1) {
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to check for it children until I find the href and if Its the right one to remove it.

Comment: Is it ok to use jquery for you? Library has a lot of traversing methods such as `find` and it will help you.

Comment: It would be a one-liner with jquery: `$('a[href=...]').parents('div.postcontainer').hide();`

Comment: You realise that blocking any functionality with *only* javascript can be easily circumvented, right?

Comment: @IlliaOlenchenko I'm using Custom Javascript for websites extension for googlechrome to run the script, it has an jquery option I think, I'll try Gerald solution.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider it did not work, I'm unsure if its the extension problem or the code problem

Comment: @SpoocyCrep I think that chain code will deal with your problem. It is a common situation to manipulate DOM with JS, but if you can solve it in 1 row, let the Nike be here, Just do it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, get the a tag of that user. It's pretty easy nowadays:

```
var a_tag = document.querySelector('a[href="member.php?u=649142"]');
```

then travel up:

```
var container_tag = a_tag.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
```

finally, do what you want to do with that node:

```
container_tag.parentNode.removeChild(container_tag);
```

Comment: This worked, but it removed only 1 message by that user, is there a way to remove all the messages?

Comment: try use querySelectorAll()

Comment: Thanks! it seem to work perfectly- Just one last thing, I noticed the forum sometimes auto-updates new posts, I still haven't tested it with the current script but I do believe the script wont remove those new popping messages. Is there a way to do that again in case of new message pops out? I did notice that in the console it writes "new post" in case of a new post being shown.

Comment: I still didn't get the context of your project: are you writing a chrome extension? such jobs are mostly done through the backend - rails, php, python etc,. In javascript part, one way is to use setInterval(callbackFunction, timeout) to monitor page update every a few seconds.

Comment: No, I'm simply creating an script and using custom javascript for website to run it, I'm doing it for my own use, I want to block users in a forum without seeing their messages, I wont post this script anywhere its for private use.